# SQL: Does having two tables require a join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two conditions in a where statement that is in two different tables, is it required to make a join between them?

like:

```
select *
from customer, order 
where customer = 'john'
and order = 'car'
```

Does it require them to have a **join** statement because I have two tables in **from** ?

Comment: If you want `everyone's orders for cars` combined in every combination with `customers called john`, then what you have is fine.  But if you ***only*** want `orders for Cars made By John`, then you need something extra; Probably something like `customer INNER JOIN order ON order.customer_id = customer.id`

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`

Comment: To clarify: Assuming that there are 100,000 orders where `order` = 'car', and 5,000 customers where `customer` = 'john', but that only 100 of the orders where `order` = 'car' are tied to customers where `customer` = 'john'. Would you be looking to get back just the 100 orders, or 500,000,000 rows (match every `customer` = 'john' with each and every `order` = 'car')

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you intend:

```
select *
from customer c cross join
     orders o
where c.customer = 'john' and o.order = 'car';
```

This is fine.  I might expect that the `orders` table would have a "customer id" of some sort.  But if you want all "john"s cross with all "car"s, then the query does what you intend.

Some people would write this as an inner join:

```
select *
from customer c join
     orders o
     on c.customer = 'john' and o.order = 'car';
```

I'm fairy neutral -- except I strongly encourage you to spell out `cross join` rather than using a comma.

Comment: I believe this is not what she is looking for: Your query will join all 'cars' order to all these people that are called John. You also need to match ids in the ON clause.

Comment: @BenjaminRacette - That's possible, but as the OP didn't provide any other details that's just a guess/inference.  As to the question of whether you need to correlate the two table or not, this answer is correct: You certainly ***can*** `CROSS JOIN` them and filter the two tables independently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely need to join those two tables to get the results you are looking for.